# how to add extra attribute properties like upload image for attribute in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes

> I want a image uploader option in Attribute Properties in magneto2

[image]

Comment: are you needed image uploader button right?

Comment: yes, i want image uploader button here for each attribute